# inserting row in the middle of a html table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table which contains two rows.

```
<tr id="row1"><td>first row</td></tr>
<tr id="row2"><td>second row</td></tr>
```

I need to insert few rows between row1 and row2 using java script.
I can achieve this by using java script create element. But I wish to add new rows using string html content. 
for example :

```
"<tr><td>This row is placed between first and second</td></tr>".insertAfter(first row Id);
```

is there way like this to add rows in between?

Comment: Yes I can use. But any reference code?

Comment: I always recommend not using jQuery, when you can. See below for a completely native JS solution.

Comment: @NickDugger Given that jQuery _is_ JS, couldn't one argue that _anything_ that can be done in jQuery _can_ be done in native JS?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use jQuery unless it is required.It adds a bloat of 19 kB and if you can do the same using plain js and are not using it specifically for doing something, you should not add it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jQuery. There is a Function [`insertAfter();`](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/)

```
$("#row1").insertAfter("your html");
```

http://jquery.com/

Comment: Suggesting to simply "use jQuery" is neither helpful nor productive. Always use native JS when you can.

Answer (score 8):

```
var newRow = document.createElement("tr");
newRow.innerHTML = "<td>This row is placed... etc.</td>";

var row2 = document.getElementById("row2");
row2.parentNode.insertBefore(newRow, row2);
```

Read up on it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore

Answer (score 0):

```
var button = document.getElementById('insert');

var table = document.getElementById('table');

button.onclick = function() {

var position=Math.round(table.rows.length / 2);

var row = table.insertRow(position);

row.innerHTML = '<td>This row is placed between '+position+' and '+(parseInt(position)+1)+'</td>';
} 

 **after that if u can use like that u can increment ur row id also:**


 var rowId = '#' + tableId + ' tr';
    var k = 0;
    $(rowId).each(function () {
        var ObjInput = $(this).find('input[type=text],input[type=radio],input[type=checkbox],textarea,select,input[type=img],input[type=hidden],input[type=button],img');
        if (ObjInput != null) {
            for (var j = 0; j < ObjInput.length; j++) {
                var inputId = $(ObjInput[j]).attr('id');
                inputId = inputId.replace(/_[0-9]{1,2}/g, '_' + k);
                $(ObjInput[j]).attr('id', inputId);
                $(ObjInput[j]).attr('name', inputId);
            }
            k++;
        }
    });
```