# How to filter in the table (so that they end up at the bottom of the table) the elements that belong to the "Film" section

Tags: javascript

I have a set of elements. Some of these are part of section "Film", others of section "Video" and still others of section "VideoYoutube". There is a special column that defines this Section.

The elements in the table that are part of section "Film" must be placed at the bottom of the table.

To be able to put the elements at the bottom of the table I know that you have to use the command:

`insertRow(-1);`

Since my table is dynamic, how can I set what I want?

```js
Items.forEach(function (item) {               
                    let child = document.createElement("tr");
                    child.innerHTML = `
                    <td>${item.id}</td>
                    <td>${item.title}</td>
                    <td>${item.image}</td> 
                    <td>${item.section}</td>
                    <td>${item.date}</td>`;
                    table.appendChild(child);
                })
```

```html
    <table id="my-table" width="90%">
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Image</th>
                <th>Section</th>
                <th>Date</th>
            </tr>

        </table>
```

To understand better, I have to filter by **Film** only

**Example to understand**

```js
let itemarr = [{
  id: 1,
  title: "image 1",
  image: "url 1",
  section: "Film",
  date: "date 1",
}, {
  id: 2,
  title: "image 2",
  image: "url 2",
  section: "Video",
  date: "date 2",
},
{
  id: 3,
  title: "image 3",
  image: "url 2",
  section: "Film",
  date: "date 2",
},
{
  id: 4,
  title: "image 4",
  image: "url 2",
  section: "Video",
  date: "date 2",
}]
itemarr.forEach(function(item) {
  let child = document.querySelector('table').insertRow(-1)
  child.innerHTML = `
                    <td>${item.id}</td>
                    <td>${item.title}</td>
                    <td>${item.image}</td> 
                    <td>${item.section}</td>
                    <td>${item.date}</td>`

})
```

```html
<table id="my-table" width="90%">
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Image</th>
    <th>Section</th>
    <th>Date</th>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Run, see error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: Items is not defined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try this one by pushing the one you want showing later to another array ?

Of course not the best solution, but easiest solution.

If you simply want to use `insertRow(-1)`, you will facing the problem of inserting item in front of the section part `th>Id</th> <th>Title</th> <th>Image</th> <th>Section</th> <th>Date</th>`, so the easiest way will using this

```js
let itemarr = [{
  id: 1,
  title: "image 1",
  image: "url 1",
  section: "Film",
  date: "date 1",
}, {
  id: 2,
  title: "image 2",
  image: "url 2",
  section: "Video",
  date: "date 2",
},
{
  id: 3,
  title: "image 3",
  image: "url 2",
  section: "Film",
  date: "date 2",
},
{
  id: 4,
  title: "image 4",
  image: "url 2",
  section: "Video",
  date: "date 2",
}];
let lateradd = []


itemarr.forEach(function(item) {

let child = document.querySelector('table').insertRow(-1);
if(item.section ==="Video"){
child.innerHTML = `
   <td>${item.id}</td>
                    <td>${item.title}</td>
                    <td>${item.image}</td> 
                    <td>${item.section}</td>
                    <td>${item.date}</td>
`;
}else{lateradd.push(item)}
})
if(lateradd){
lateradd.forEach(function(i){
document.querySelector('table').insertRow(-1).innerHTML =`
   <td>${i.id}</td>
                    <td>${i.title}</td>
                    <td>${i.image}</td> 
                    <td>${i.section}</td>
                    <td>${i.date}</td>
`
})

}
```

```html
<table id="my-table" width="90%">
  <tr id='section'>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Image</th>
    <th>Section</th>
    <th>Date</th>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: To be honest, not a very good solution since required two array, but think of the way of massive code to consider insert element at the second row, this will work, but If anyone find better soluation, i am free to delete mine.

Comment: Would there be another method? Not necessarily using insertRow (-1). If you have another tip even better

Comment: @s_o_p_h_i_a, I have been try to search and code for 20 minutes for this, but seems not working (i am not pretty good at dealing  with table). but you could try to see: e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23342034/inserting-row-in-the-middle-of-a-html-table-using-javascript

Comment: @s_o_p_h_i_a, maybe I will try to see these days and will tell you if i have better solutation

Comment: I tried too but without success. Perfect thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your object based on a property (section).  Here I show how to do that with the "Film" value.

Now just do this for each in whichever order you want.

This is very basic as a example you can work from and this can be much more "elegant" by calling for example a function and passing the "section" name and using it, setting an object with the "orders" of these and processing that, things like that.

```js
let itemarr = [{
    id: 1,
    title: "image 1",
    image: "url 1",
    section: "Film",
    date: "date 1",
  }, {
    id: 2,
    title: "image 2",
    image: "url 2",
    section: "Video",
    date: "date 2",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "image 3",
    image: "url 2",
    section: "Film",
    date: "date 2",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: "image 4",
    image: "url 2",
    section: "Video",
    date: "date 2",
  }
];
const resultsFilm = itemarr.filter(obj => {
  return obj.section === "Film";
});
resultsFilm.forEach(function(item) {
  let child = document.querySelector('table').insertRow(-1)
  child.innerHTML = `
                    <td>${item.id}</td>
                    <td>${item.title}</td>
                    <td>${item.image}</td> 
                    <td>${item.section}</td>
                    <td>${item.date}</td>`

});
```

```html
<table id="my-table" width="90%">
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Image</th>
    <th>Section</th>
    <th>Date</th>
  </tr>

</table>
```

A bit more "elegant" solution using some objects and functions to process them by sorting in the order we specified.

```js
let itemarr = [{
    id: 1,
    title: "image 1",
    image: "url 1",
    section: "Film",
    date: "date 1",
  }, {
    id: 2,
    title: "image 2",
    image: "url 2",
    section: "Video",
    date: "date 2",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "image 3",
    image: "url 2",
    section: "Film",
    date: "date 2",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: "image 4",
    image: "url 2",
    section: "Video",
    date: "date 2",
  }
];
let sectionOrder = [{
  section: "Video",
  order: 1
}, {
  section: "Film",
  order: 5
}, {
  section: "YouTube",
  order: 2
}];


function showSection(sectionName) {
  const resultsFiltered = itemarr.filter(obj => {
    return obj.section === sectionName;
  });
  resultsFiltered.forEach(function(item) {
    let child = document.querySelector('table').insertRow(-1)
    child.innerHTML = `
                    <td>${item.id}</td>
                    <td>${item.title}</td>
                    <td>${item.image}</td> 
                    <td>${item.section}</td>
                    <td>${item.date}</td>`

  });
}
// sort by the order
sectionOrder.sort((a, b) => (a.order > b.order) ? 1 : -1);
//console.log(sectionOrder);
//process sections in the order we sorted, use that to refer to the data.
sectionOrder.forEach(function(sec) {
  showSection(sec.section);
});
```

```html
<table id="my-table" width="90%">
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Image</th>
    <th>Section</th>
    <th>Date</th>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: How come the lines with id equal to 2 and 4 are not present? These must be present, not deleted. Those with section "Film" just have to be inserted at the bottom of the table

Comment: I only did the one example "Film" asked for - build from that.

Comment: I added a second example with sorting and some functions - it can be still more elegant but is based on your original code.